# How do I explicitly send key-value observing notifications from an NSResponder?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, nstouchbar

I'm trying to make a NSTouchBar in an SDL application and I need to attach a responder to the NSWindow object (that's the only access SDL gives into the Cocoa windowing system).

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstouchbar

> If you explicitly adopt the NSTouchBarProvider protocol in an object,
>   **you must also explicitly send the associated key-value observing
>   notifications** within NSTouchBar methods; this lets the system respond
>   appropriately to changes in the bar.

What does that mean and how do I do it?   I see lots of documentation about how to subscribe to the notifications, but not how to send them?

Right now I have:

```
@interface MyTouchBarResponder : NSResponder <NSTouchBarDelegate>

- (id)init;
- (NSTouchBar *)makeTouchBar;
- (nullable NSTouchBarItem *)touchBar:(NSTouchBar *)touchBar makeItemForIdentifier:(NSTouchBarItemIdentifier)identifier;
@property(strong, readonly) NSTouchBar *touchBar;

@end
```

and I'm attaching it to the window with the code from a previous question I asked here: [How to create an NSTouchBar from an NSWindow object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686370/how-to-create-an-nstouchbar-from-an-nswindow-object)

```
touchBarResponder.nextResponder = window.nextResponder;
window.nextResponder = touchBarResponder;
```

but my callbacks aren't ever being called (I put `exit(0)` in them to make it very obvious).   When I hack the code directly into the SDL library, things work as expected, but that's not a viable permanent solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get this working? Any github repo? I'm trying to add touchbar support to an editor via a plugin that's loaded dynamically after the window has been created, so I think I'm in a similar situation. I can get makeTouchBar to be called, but touchBar is never called.

Comment: @dsvensson I did but what I ended up with was sort of a jumble.. here it is, but it's a bunch of mixed up code for both creating it manually and loading it from a NIB file mixed in with stuff that is for my game, so you'll have to sort though it..  that said, it did actually mostly sort of work.. https://gist.github.com/xaxxon/fbc900e51448c7e2bbff663c061050c9

Comment: Doesn't work. I need to add setting firstresponder to nil and back to its previous value for makeTouchBar to execute, and touchBar will still never execute.

Comment: @dsvensson sorry.  I don't know much about this.. I just know this is what worked for me after creating a window with SDL.

Answer (score 1):

First, your custom responder should conform to `NSTouchBarProvider` (in the above, you declare the `touchBar` property, but not the explicit conformance)

Second, you want to make sure that your custom responder is in the responder chain of the window (whether the first responder or just later in the chain). After adjusting the responder chain with your above code, you want to call `-makeFirstResponder:` and pass in some view in the window (if you need that view to be first responder) or with the custom responder object. You should then verify that the window's `firstResponder` is that object.

With these in place, you should get at least one call to `touchBar` after the window is shown and made key.

To answer the question on key-value observing notifications, that is needed for when you want to change the actual NSTouchBar object being returned from `touchBar`. In the general case this isn't necessary, since it's unnecessary in the static touch bar case, and even in the dynamic case, you can rely on just setting the `defaultItemIdentifiers` on the previously created touch bar and it will update. However, should you need to change the touch bar object, you need to ensure that `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` are sent for `touchBar` when you change the return value. [This developer documentation on KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) goes into much more detail.